# Odd behaviour with Xcode

Tags: objective-c, image, sender

I haven't been programming for that long, but this is really puzzling me.
I have a memory card game that I am developing for the iPhone and it's running fine. I decided I fancy add a feature to it, which is that when player 2 is playing, the cards flip vertically so that you can put the phone on the table and each player can see the cards without turning the phone. Here is the method for when you press the cards.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    self.clickCount ++;

    self.playerTurn = [[PlayerTurn alloc]init];

    [self.playerTurn turnDecider];

    NSUInteger senderID = [sender tag];

    if (self.playerTurn.PlayerOneIsPlaying) {

        NSLog(@"player one is playing");

        self.tileImage = [self.myCards.Images objectAtIndex:senderID];

        [sender setImage:self.tileImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else{

        UIButton *butt = sender;

        NSLog(@"player two is playing");

        self.tileImage = [self.myCards.Images objectAtIndex:senderID];

        [butt setImage:self.tileImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

         butt.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);

    }
```

I am posting the whole method first, but the part that isn't working is this one

```
if (self.playerTurn.PlayerOneIsPlaying) {

    NSLog(@"player one is playing");

    self.tileImage = [self.myCards.Images objectAtIndex:senderID];

    [sender setImage:self.tileImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 }else{

     NSLog(@"player two is playing");

     UIButton *butt = sender;

     self.tileImage = [self.myCards.Images objectAtIndex:senderID];

     [butt setImage:self.tileImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      butt.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);

      }
```

The strange thing is this. When I launch the app, at first everything works fine, but after a while, player one starts seeing their cards flipped or not randomly. The strange thing is that on the console, I can see the NSLog messages "player one is playing" and "player two is playing" when they should be, so I know that the right block of the if statement is being executed. How on earth can this be happening?? It's behaving like it's executing a few lines from the if statement and then a few from the else statement?? Has anyone come across something similar? Or am I missing something here? Help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe try using a `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` on player one also.

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug!

Comment: The first comment solved the issue